# Is every real-valued polynomial (whose roots are all non-real) of even degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I vaguely remember (maybe misremember) hearing that, given a polynomial $f$, that
$$ 
f(\alpha) = 0 \implies f(\overline{\alpha}) =0
$$
That is, the conjugate of a root of is also a root. Further,
$$\alpha = \overline{\alpha} \Longleftrightarrow
\alpha = Re(\alpha) $$
Now, let $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Let $deg(f) = n$.
Let every root be non-real.
Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ be the roots.
We can pair these roots off as
$$
(\alpha_1, \overline{\alpha_1}), \ldots, (\alpha_i, \overline{\alpha_i})
$$
Assume $n$ is odd. Since complex conjugates are unique, we get that the roots are
$$
(\alpha_1, \overline{\alpha_1}), \ldots, (\alpha_i, \overline{\alpha_i}), \alpha_j
$$
to ensure there are an odd number of roots. But then, $\overline{\alpha_j}$ is a root, so we get
$$
(\alpha_1, \overline{\alpha_1}), \ldots, (\alpha_i, \overline{\alpha_i}), (\alpha_j, \overline{\alpha_j})
$$

So,  $n$ is even.

Comment: That's correct. Or, otherwise put, a real polynomial of odd degree must have a root equal to its own complex conjugate i.e. a real root.

Comment: This works. Alternatively, if $p(x)$ has odd degree note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)=\pm\infty$ (depending on whether the leading coefficient is positive or negative) and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}=\mp\infty$; so by the Intemediate Value Theorem, there must be a point where the polynomial is equal to $0$.